# psycopg2 - Adding aggregation to a script passing list as columns

Tags: python, psycopg2

I have a list of columns that I am trying to pass as columns as part of a select statement as shown below:

```
list_name = ['col_a', 'col_b']
```

Trying to pass this list into the below query:

```
query = """SELECT {}
           FROM table""".format(', '.join(str(field) for field in list_name))
```

The above works well, I am trying to alter the above script such that I add an aggregation value as a new column as `sum(id)`

```
query = """SELECT {}, sum(id)
           FROM table group by {}""".format(', '.join(str(field) for field in list_name))
```

The above throws an error `IndexError: tuple index out of range`

Trying to find where am I going wrong in the above edit of adding an aggregation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second query you need to pass the fields twice (once for `SELECT` and once for `GPOUP`):

```
fields = ', '.join(str(field) for field in list_name)
query = """SELECT {}, sum(id) FROM table group by {}""".format(fields, fields)
```